Unity - C# - Noob Question - Undesired outcome while using 'LookAt' function when parent object's rotation changes
-I am new to programming, I have primarily been learning it for game development through Unity using C#.
-I am currently working on a 3D version of Snake where the player moves around the surface of a cube instead of a flat 2D plane.
-I am writing the code for the segments of the players body to rotate when the player turns so the models turn appropriately. It works by the script attached to the head of the snake using the lookAt function to turn the back of the visual model towards the location it was just at.
-This is a example of it working normally, the head of the snake starts at the center cube moves up, up, then left:
Snake Operating properly
-It works mostly fine except when the cube the player is on rotates when they turn to a new side. When the cube rotates the segments all look at weird angles and the lookAt target Vector3 doesn't match the Vector3 of the point I am feeding it. This affects all segments of the snake
-This is an image of the snake turning around the left side, the image is taken from scene view:
Snake rotation is strange when on a corner
-Here is the code for the head of the player:
public GameObject ourPoint;
public GameObject thisPoint;
public GameObject playerSegmentPrefab;
public List<GameObject> segments;
public float secondsSinceLastMovement;
public float timeBetweenMovements;
public int direction;
public bool pointsSet = false;

[SerializeField] private GameObject playerVisual;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 lookAtTarget;
[SerializeField] private GameObject a;
public bool test;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    References.player = this;
    direction = 4;
    lookAtTarget = new Vector3(0, -5, -1.5f);
}

void Start()
{
    GameObject firstSegement = Instantiate(playerSegmentPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    segments.Insert(0, firstSegement);
    firstSegement.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    GameObject secondSegment = Instantiate(playerSegmentPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    segments.Insert(1, secondSegment);
    secondSegment.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform);
    Player_Segment_Behaviour firstSegmentScript = firstSegement.GetComponent<Player_Segment_Behaviour>();
    firstSegmentScript.follower = secondSegment;
}

void Move(int upDownRightLeft)
{
    int currentPeak = References.ground.peak;
    int currentFace = References.ground.face;
    Point_Script ourPointScript = ourPoint.GetComponent<Point_Script>();
    if(upDownRightLeft == 1)
    {
        thisPoint = ourPointScript.upPoint;
    }

    if(upDownRightLeft == 2)
    {
        thisPoint = ourPointScript.downPoint;
    }

    if(upDownRightLeft == 3)
    {
        thisPoint = ourPointScript.rightPoint;
    }

    if(upDownRightLeft == 4)
    {
        thisPoint = ourPointScript.leftPoint;
    }
    Point_Script thisPointScript = thisPoint.GetComponent<Point_Script>();
    if(thisPoint != null)
    {
    if(ourPointScript.ourCube == thisPointScript.ourCube)
    {
        References.ground.face = thisPointScript.compass;
    }
    }



    Player_Segment_Behaviour firstSegmentScript = segments[0].GetComponent<Player_Segment_Behaviour>();
    firstSegmentScript.Move(ourPoint, upDownRightLeft, thisPoint);
    lookAtTarget = ourPoint.transform.position;
    ourPoint = thisPoint;
    if(thisPointScript.ourCube == ourPointScript.ourCube)
    {
        References.ground.ChangeTarget(upDownRightLeft);
    } 

    secondsSinceLastMovement = 0;
    if(test == false)
    {
    playerVisual.transform.LookAt(lookAtTarget);
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    playerVisual.transform.LookAt(lookAtTarget);

    if(test == true)
    {
    lookAtTarget = a.transform.position;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i ++)
    {
        if(segments[i] != null)
        {
        Player_Segment_Behaviour thisSegment = segments[i].GetComponent<Player_Segment_Behaviour>();
        thisSegment.test = test;
        thisSegment.a = a;
        }
    }

    if(References.ground.points.Count >= 149 && pointsSet == false)
    {
        Player_Segment_Behaviour firstSegmentScript = segments[0].GetComponent<Player_Segment_Behaviour>();
        Player_Segment_Behaviour secondSegmentScript = segments[1].GetComponent<Player_Segment_Behaviour>();
        Point_Script ourPointScript = ourPoint.GetComponent<Point_Script>();
        firstSegmentScript.ourPoint = ourPointScript.downPoint;
        firstSegmentScript.gameObject.transform.position = ourPointScript.downPoint.transform.position;
        Point_Script firstSegementPointScript = firstSegmentScript.ourPoint.GetComponent<Point_Script>();
        secondSegmentScript.ourPoint = firstSegementPointScript.downPoint;
        secondSegmentScript.gameObject.transform.position =                   firstSegementPointScript.downPoint.transform.position;
        pointsSet = true;
    }
    transform.position = ourPoint.transform.position;
    secondsSinceLastMovement += Time.deltaTime;

    if(References.ground.cycleActive == false)
    {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && direction != 3)
    {
        direction = 4;
        Move(direction);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && direction != 4)
    {
        direction = 3;
        Move(direction);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && direction != 2)
    {
        direction = 1;
        Move(direction);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && direction != 1)
    {
        direction = 2;
        Move(direction);
    }

    if(secondsSinceLastMovement >= timeBetweenMovements)
    {
        Move(direction);
    }
    }

(The test boolean was just to test what direction the segments were looking at when I would set them up, I would have a gameObject ( a ) be the target and fiddle with the model until it line up with "a" like it was the point the segment would look at)
Any help what so ever would be greatly appreciated thank you!
-I wasn't sure if it was an issue with the cubes rotation or something with the segments code so I wrote a script to see if the segments' direction changed in the same way if the cube moved on its own without the segments moving and the same issue occurred.
-I tried having the camera move around the cube instead of the cube rotating to always face the camera but that caused the same issue.
-I am expecting the segment to look in the direction of its previous point on the previous side of the cube.
-I'm assuming this is an issue with some setting concerning the angles operating relative to themselves instead of the world position but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried looking it up on YouTube, etc. but either couldn't type in the correct description or it's a different problem entirely. I tried looking at most info on rotation, I'm not entirely familiar with Quaternions yet.

While I agree I wouldnt expect your snake to be in the cube from a user perspective,  Its not clear that the lookat is at fault in the picture.  So, quaternions do tend to fry your brain, they are good at that. However, i would expect the snake peices to follow each other in a follow the leader senario, so piece 22, needs to step into the last place piece 21 had, so whether thats 3d or 2d doesnt matter. the only bit the needs to know is the head, and it can rely on a level of colliders and lack there of, as to whether its going round an edge.

Yes, that is how the other segments work they pass the last point back through out themselves one at a time. The reason I was using look at was to have the segments easily rotate to connect, it might not have been clear i nthe images but each segment is made up of four of the spheres and move between a fixed point at each cube so they act like a straight line and if they do not rotate when they reach their new destination after a turn they just always point up instead of to the side if your turn left for example. This was my best plan based on my understanding of rotations, if there's a better

way I am open to it, however I would still like to know why the look at function is returning an unpredicted result for future reference if this happens again. Thank you for responding.

what is "ourpoint" supposed to reference? you set the target to be it, but from this code theres no way to know what that is, and as its public any code somewhere else could be changing it to the wrong thing, who knows

so for every possible space on the cube the player can go there is a gameObject that are called points, the ourPoint refers to the one the player is currently on, the point has references for which points are up, down, left, right of it that tell the player which point to move to next based on what direction, I'll change it to private but I don't think it's being altered elsewhere because the player movement works fine, it's just the visual rotation that is the issue. Originally the ourPoint is set by the cube so it knows where the center is, later on it is change whenever the player moves.
